# How can I solve error of NDK - I can't build my app

Tags: android-ndk, ndk-build

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\Abir CSE\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\TBL Office Project\ASS\library\src\main\cpp\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\TBL Office Project\ASS\library\src\main\cpp\Application.mk APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=D:/TBL Office Project/ASS/library/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\TBL Office Project\ASS\library\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}

'C:\Users\Abir' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Don't use paths that contain spaces.

Comment: ok let me try @Michael

Comment: @Michael Same Problem shows. I remove all space from my project path

Comment: That seems very unlikely, unless you forgot to also update your build scripts with the new path and do a full rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android NDK, no paths may include spaces. This refers to:

- project root
- directory names inside the project
- paths to 3rd party libraries and dependency projects
- path to Android SDK
- path to NDK itself

In your case, Android SDK was installed in `C:\Users\Abir CSE\AppData\Local\Android`. Move it to a directory outside your %HOME%.

Comment: Let me try @Alex_Cohn